# ColdFusion URL variable of a selectlist value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a select list that I am populating via a call to a CFC

```
<select class="required" name="customer_checkout" id="customer_checkout" tabindex="0" onchange="PopulateGrandTotal();">
            <option>Please make a selection</option></select>
```

Once a user makes a selection I have them being directed to a payment gateway for a checkout process and the I am required to provide them with a call back URL for when the transaction is complete. I would like like to provided a URL variable in that callback URL of the value of the selection made from my selectlist, but I am unsure of how to do that.

I was thinking I could get the value on the fly via javascript by something like this:

```
var variable = encodeURIComponent($('#customer_checkout').val());
```

But I don't know how to get that into a URL variable.

My callback url looks something like this currently:

```
"https://www.myurl.com/pos/check_out.cfm?msg=1"
```

I would like to add another URL variable after the current msg variable.

Comment: Do it the easy way.  Have the user submit the form.  Process the form variables.  Generate the variable you need and add it to the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing the redirect via javascript and you have the URL encoded value and you have the URL itself, you can do a simple concatenation via javascript like `var newURL = "https://www.myurl.com/pos/check_out.cfm?msg=1&myvar=" + variable;` If this doesn't answer the question, could you update your question with full sample code (i.e. gist, plunker, jsfiddle, etc)?